# Load Data dropdown in modal window

Tags: .net, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a modal window in my ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS app. On that modal window, I have a dropdown that I should load with an array of items data but when I open this window, the dropdown has not any data.

```
<md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="ProductID" style="display:inline-block">Products</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="ProductID" name="ProductID" ng-options="p.ProductID as p.ProductName for p in listProductos" ng-model="productos.ProductID" required>
                    <option value="" style="font-weight: bold;">--Choose a product--</option>                                                            
                </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ProductID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-dialog-content>
```

And the code to load is:

```
ang.controller("EditPedidosCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "PedidosService", "$mdDialog", function ($scope, $routeParams, PedidosService, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.listProductos = [];
    PedidosService.getAllProducts().then(function (d) {
        $scope.listProductos = d.data.productos;
    });
}
```

Comment: post your json data

Comment: I resolve the problem with     scope: $scope,        
            preserveScope: true